# How to disable the auto appear of statusBar in android in full screen mode

Tags: android, xml

I know how to make an activity with a full screen in android  , but i want to know if there is a way to disable the auto appear of statusBar when clicking in the top of the screen , i want to make it like in games .

Answer (score 0):

Well You Can make Full screen In `Immersive` and `Non_Immersive`

You are talking about immersive fullscreen 
 Use This Code

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    if (hasFocus) {
        decorView
                .setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    }
}
```

}

ANd You Can go Through this page To Know More

https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html